# How to call a method exist in ActionBar Tab Fragment from main activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabs

I have an application which uses ActionBar Tab Fragment for categorizing data in different tabs.  I need to call a method from Tab Fragment when i presses a button from main activity( tab activity).  I tried below code

**Camera Details Activity**

```
public class CameraDetails extends Activity {
ActionBar.Tab networkTab, userTab;
Fragment networkFragmentTab = new NetworkFragmentTab();
Fragment userFragmentTab = new UserFragmentTab();

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.cameradetails);

    // Asking for the default ActionBar element that our platform supports.
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

    // Screen handling while hiding ActionBar icon.
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

    // Screen handling while hiding Actionbar title.
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    // Creating ActionBar tabs.
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Setting custom tab icons.
    networkTab = actionBar.newTab().setText("Network"); //.setIcon(R.drawable.bmw_logo);
    userTab = actionBar.newTab().setText("User Account");

    // Setting tab listeners.
    networkTab.setTabListener(new TabListener(networkFragmentTab));
    userTab.setTabListener(new TabListener(userFragmentTab));

    // Adding tabs to the ActionBar.
    actionBar.addTab(networkTab);
    actionBar.addTab(userTab);

    actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(1);
    }

public void onClick(View v){
  // call method validate from NetworkFragment like networkfragment.validate();
    }
}
}
```

**NetworkFragment**

```
public class NetworkFragmentTab extends Fragment {
View rootView;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.network_layout, container, false);
    return rootView;
}

public boolean Validate(){
    EditText etIpAddress = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.cd_ip_address);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), etIpAddress.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return true;
}
 }
```

I like to call method **validate()** of NetworkFragmentTab from onClick.

Comment: do you got any error?

Comment: @SathishKumarJ No error the above onClick code just shows each Tab Name.  Please see my edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code for callback via `Interface`. You have to create one `Interface` and that `Interface` will have one method which will be used to call the method of `Fragment` from your `Activity`. Try below code approach, it will solve your problem.

```
class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private MyInterface mInterface;

    public interface MyInterface {
        void theMethodOfInterface();
    }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.cameradetails);
    ...
  }

  public void onClick(View v) {
    mInterface.theMethodOfInterface();
  }

  public void setMyListener(MyInterface listner) {
    this.mInterface = listener;
  }
}
```

The Fragment is as below:

```
class MyFragment extends Fragment implements MyInterface {
    ...

      @Override
  public void onCreateView(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...// your code
    ((MyActivity)getActivity()).setMyListener(this);
    ...// your code
  }

    public void someMethodOfFragment() {
        ...
        // your code for method of fragment here
    }

    @Override
    public void theMethodOfInterface() {
        someMethodOfFragment();
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi friend.  Where is **MyListener** ?

Comment: OK friend.  How can i redesign interface for calling methods from multiple fragments.  Suppose i want call a method from **userFragmentTab**

Comment: I gave you an example which calls the Fragment method from the Activity. This is not for calling Activity method from the Fragment

Comment: What i mean is that I want to call a method from **userFragmentTab** (another fragment).  How can i modify/reuse the specified interface or create a separate interface for each fragment

Comment: Which method you want to call from UserFragmentTab ?

Comment: A method named validate2()

Comment: Create a separate Interface for each delegate method for individual Fragment, You can achieve it by taking my sample code as an example, All you have to do is: create an Interface, implement it into some Fragment of which method you want to call outside and then set the call back listener from the caller class and then just call that particular Interface method from that caller class. If you are unable to do that then give it a try and if not able to do that then post your incomplete code, I will help you

Answer (score 1):

The traditional way is to declare a callback interface in your Activity and let your Fragment implement it, then connect them together. Here is the guidelines: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#EventCallbacks.

The better way is to use something like Message Bus to remove strong dependencies between your Fragment and Activity. There are plenty of articles saying about this.

If you want to structure your application better and get rid of the headache in UI stuffs' communication, I recommend you to adopt a Model-View-Presenter framework. Here is an example: http://robo-creative.github.io/mvp.

Comment: I want to call a method exist in tab fragment from tab activity

Comment: Then can you just simply declare a callback interface in your activity and let your fragment implement that interface?